# What are the valid list of WebKeyTypes for Azure Key Vault API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to create a new Key in [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) via the API   [KeyVaultClient.CreateKeyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn891724.aspx):

```
public Task<KeyBundle> CreateKeyAsync (
    string vaultAddress,
    string keyType,
    KeyAttributes keyAttributes)
```

Documentation for `keyType` is:

> The type of key to create (one of the valid WebKeyTypes)

### What are the valid WebKeyTypes??

---

I've searched through MSDN documentation and didn't find anything. [Powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn868048.aspx) call doesn't seem to need this parameter??:

```
Parameter Set: Create
Add-AzureKeyVaultKey 
          [-VaultName] <String> 
          [-Name] <String> 
          -Destination <String> {HSM | Software} 
          [-Disable] 
          [-Expires <DateTime]> ] 
          [-KeyOps <String[]> ] 
          [-NotBefore <DateTime]> ] 
          [-Tags <System.Collections.Hashtable> ] 
          [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [`Azure KeyVault SDK on Github`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/52fc67253a176bea01c37c164f71c7eba8eaedba/src/KeyVault/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault), only thing I was able to find was [`JsonWebKeyTypes`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/52fc67253a176bea01c37c164f71c7eba8eaedba/src/KeyVault/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/WebKey/JsonWebKeyTypes.cs). Based on the source code, here're the possible values:

```
public const string EllipticCurve = "EC";
public const string Rsa           = "RSA";
public const string RsaHsm        = "RSA-HSM";
public const string Octet         = "oct";
```

However looking at the [`REST API documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_KeyTypes), I am led to believe that only `RSA` and `RSA-HSM` are currently supported.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Github, I've left an issue up there for them: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/2086.

Comment: How did you determine only `RSA` and `RSA-HSM` are supported?

Comment: Please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_KeyTypes. It only talks about RSA & RSA-HSM.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually documented at [Key Vault MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_KeyTypes):

> The initial Azure Key Vault release supports RSA keys only; future
>   releases may support other key types such as symmetric and elliptic
>   curve.
>
> - RSA: A 2048bit RSA key. This is a "soft" key, which is processed in software by Key Vault but is stored encrypted at rest using a system
>     key that is in an HSM. Clients may import an existing RSA key or
>     request that Azure Key Vault generate one.
> - RSA-HSM: An RSA key that is processed in an HSM. RSA-HSM keys are protected in one of the Azure Key Vault HSM Security Worlds (there is
>     a Security World per geography to maintain isolation). Clients may
>     import a RSA key, either in soft form or by exporting from a
>     compatible HSM device, or request that Azure Key Vault generate one.
>     This key type adds the T attribute to the JWK obtain to carry the HSM
>     key material.

As of this writing, Key Vault doesn't support EC and oct keys.

Answer (score 0):

After disassembling the `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll` it looks like this the `KeyType`s that `CreateKeyAsync` wants:

```
/// <summary>Supported JsonWebKey key types (kty)</summary>
public static class JsonWebKeyType
{    
   public const string EllipticCurve = "EC";
   public const string Rsa = "RSA";
   public const string RsaHsm = "RSA-HSM";
   public const string Octet = "oct";    
}
```

I tried using `JsonWebKeyType.Octet` and now I get a new error, but that's a new question.

Comment: If anyone from MSFT team see's this, it would be really nice if you just made this an Enum or at least updated your documentation to explicitly point to this class.   Was quite the pain in the ass to track it down.